# Not Able to include header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hi I have created a project in vs 2005. I have created a header file A.h.
Similarly I have added A.cxx in a folder called implementation.  In .cxx file I have included A.h.

I have used #include "A.h". But when I am compiling it is telling A.h not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include files one of two ways:

1. As a relative path to your .cpp file (example assumes a.h is in a folder above your .cpp file)

   ```
    #include "..\a.h"
   ```
2. Or by adding the header location to your project include directories

   Right click on project, goto properties, under configuration properties, goto VC++ Directories (add the path in the ";" separated list)

Answer (score 1):

Is the header file A.h in the same directory as A.cxx? It needs to be, if you use the #include statement you mention above.

Comment: I have a folder xyz/A.h and xyz/abc/a.cxx

Comment: Then in that case, #include "../A.h" is the correct statement to place in A.cxx. The reason being "../" means up one directory from the current directory, i.e. "xyz/".